# What other good C++ books are there?

Tags: questions, idiomatic-language

> I've started reading a book about C++ written by [some author]. The book is very good. **What other good C++ books are there?**

Does the selected question sound natural? Do native speakers say that way?

Comment: What sounds unnatural to you in that sentence?

Comment: Probably I've rarely heard that form of a question - What something are there? So the question is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question:

> What other good C++ books are there?

is correct. It is a specific form of:

> What **other things** are there?

where **"other things"** = **"other C++ books"**